# java multithreading in virtual Multicore single cpu vs multiple physical core cpus

Tags: java, multithreading

Here is an use case of general java multithreading implementation:

1. I have one cpu with four virtual cores.
2. I have four cpus with four physical cores.

Which hardware should I choose to efficiently implement a multithreaded application. As far as I know, the number of cores in cpu(virtual/physical) is abstracted to the jvm by the operating system and the jvm cannot differentiate between virtual/physical cores. However, what hardware configuration should be more efficient between the two above mentioned options?

Comment: If you need performance always prefer hardware and forget about virtualization

Comment: If you want to know for sure you should run some benchmarks. By "virtual cores" do you mean virtual machine with emulated cores or do you mean hyper-threaded CPU?

Comment: FWIW, I believe that communication between cores in a single CPU are faster than they are between separate physical CPUs because it doesn't have to occur over the main system bus. This is important for synchronizing access to memory among other things.

Comment: @cyroxis By virtual cores I meant to say hyper threaded cpu.